# Error: 'Transaction' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data, swiftui

I am writing an app in SwiftUI using CoreData. I am getting an error in one view:

> 'Transaction' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context

Because of this error Preview doesn't work for this view. However, I can build the app and run in Simulator.

The code I am having problem is as follows:

```
import SwiftUI

struct TransactionsListView: View {

    var fetchRequest: FetchRequest<Transaction>
    var transactions: FetchedResults<Transaction> { fetchRequest.wrappedValue }

    var body: some View {

        Text("test")
//      Some other code that doesn't make the error
    }

    init(filter: Bool?) {
        if let filter = filter {
            fetchRequest = FetchRequest<Transaction>(entity: Transaction.entity(), sortDescriptors: [], predicate: NSPredicate(format: "income = %d", filter))
        } else {
            fetchRequest = FetchRequest<Transaction>(entity: Transaction.entity(), sortDescriptors: [])
        }
    }

}

struct TransactionsListView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TransactionsListView(filter: true)
    }
}
```

What does this error mean and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is diagnostic log:

> ```
> TestCoreDataBinding.Transaction:1:33: note: found this candidate
> @objc(Transaction) public class Transaction : NSManagedObject {
>                                 ^
> SwiftUI.Transaction:2:15: note: found this candidate
> public struct Transaction {
> ```

You have explicitly specify your module name for confused type, like below:

```
var fetchRequest: FetchRequest<TestCoreDataBinding.Transaction>
var transactions: FetchedResults<TestCoreDataBinding.Transaction> { fetchRequest.wrappedValue }
```

in every place of this file where `Transaction` is used as generics type.

Comment: Thanks, Asperi, but I am getting following errors now: `Use of undeclared type 'TestCoreDataBinding'` and `Use of unresolved identifier 'TestCoreDataBinding'`. I have also tried renaming entity to NewTransaction, but this gives me errors like: `Use of undeclared type 'NewTransaction'` and `Use of unresolved identifier 'NewTransaction'`

Comment: `TestCoreDataBinding` is name of my module (app name), you have to set it there your. There is no need to rename entity. If you unclear which name of your module is used you can see it in clicking on Diagnostic button in Preview when get error and find lines like as I posted.

Comment: Ahaaaa :) Now I get it. Thanks, Asperi. Changing `<Transaction>` to `<MyAppName.Transaction>` fixed the problem.

Comment: No, sorry. I have accepted this answer too fast. It helped in my test app. But when I changed `<Transaction>` to `<market.Transaction>` in my app named "market", Preview is crashing and giving me long Crash Log which I don't understand. This app is localised (it supports 2 languages). Could this be the problem?

Comment: Restart Xcode, clean / rebuild? Really 'market' with lowercased 'm'? Localization shoud not affect

Comment: Yes, "market" - all lowercase. Is it a problem? I have tried Clean Build Folder and Build again. Also tried restarting Xcode. Preview crashed again. I've found crash logs file in Finder and opened it in Xcode. In Debug Navigator it shows error `Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread (0)` on line `var transactions: FetchedResults<market.Transaction> { fetchRequest.wrappedValue }`

Comment: No, lowercase should not be a problem... It sounds as something project specific... hmm... don't know... do you have stored records? - try to clean-up/reset/delete database.

Comment: How to reset/delete database? It crashes on Preview. Is database stored in Preview? Also, I have tried to change `<Transaction>` into `<market.Transaction>` line by line. It fails to compile preview because of 'Transaction' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context... until this line: `var transactions: FetchedResults<Transaction> { fetchRequest.wrappedValue }`. After I add there `market.` before `Transaction` this error message changes to `Cannot preview in this file... market.app may have crashed.`

Comment: To clarify... your fix seems to work for most lines of code, but doesn't work for `var transactions: FetchedResults<market.Transaction> { fetchRequest.wrappedValue }` where it crashes preview of the app

Comment: Asperi, I think your solution is correct. But my app is still crashing on line: `var transactions: FetchedResults<market.Transaction> { fetchRequest.wrappedValue }`. I have tried changing entity name as well and the app crashes on the same line. I think there is a problem with my code, not your solution. I will investigate more and come back to this question. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem is your choice of name for the entity, which clashes with a structure defined in SwiftUI.  See [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/transaction).

Try using a different entity name.

Comment: Thanks. I would never guess. I don't know how to solve it, though. I have changed name in the file to be NewTransaction. And changed Entity and Class name to NewTransaction as well. I am getting many errors now. In every place where I am using this NewTransaction name, I see errors: `Use of undeclared type 'NewTransaction'`and `Use of unresolved identifier 'NewTransaction'`

Comment: If you’ve changed the name of the entity and class in the model editor, Xcode should generate the required classes - unless you’ve switched codegen to manual?  If so, you will need to amend the class files as well.  Also worth cleaning and then rebuilding in case it’s just an Xcode glitch.

Comment: No, I didn’t change it to manual. Code gen is Class Definition. I have cleaned Build Folder and later Build again. Still getting errors. Is there some other cleaning I should use?

Comment: Thank you very much, pbasdf. Your answer helped me a lot. But finally I have used Asperi's fix for my problem as changing names didn't work for me (maybe I did something wrong or it's a bug in Xcode).